# "CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target" The errors appeared when I catkin_make a ROS working space

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

When I catkin_make my ROS working space, it's always was finished by the error:

```
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: XX
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "XX".
```

According to the information of XX, I find the error may be located in one of the ROS packages. There is a CMakeList.txt and a package.xml in the package. **But I haven't exactly known what resulted in the errors, and I haven't solved this problem until now.** Below I show the exact codes of the two files.

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(omnicopter_controller)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs 
  mav_msgs 
  nav_msgs 
  sensor_msgs 
  cmake_modules 
  roscpp 
  rospy 
  std_msgs
)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include ${Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  LIBRARIES omnicopter_controller
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs mav_msgs nav_msgs roscpp sensor_msgs
  DEPENDS Eigen3
)

include_directories(
  include 
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(omnicopter_position_controller_pub
  src/omnicopter_position_controller_pub.cpp
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_position_controller_pub ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_position_controller_pub
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(omnicopter_position_controller_sub
  src/omnicopter_position_controller_sub.cpp
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_position_controller_sub ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_position_controller_sub
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(omnicopter_attitude_controller_pub
  src/omnicopter_attitude_controller_pub.cpp
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_attitude_controller_pub ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_attitude_controller_pub
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(omnicopter_attitude_controller_sub
  src/omnicopter_attitude_controller_sub.cpp
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_attitude_controller_sub ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_attitude_controller_sub
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller_pub
  src/omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller_pub.cpp
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller_pub ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller_pub
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller_sub
  src/omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller_sub.cpp
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller_sub ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller_sub
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(omnicopter_control_allocator_pub
  src/omnicopter_control_allocator_pub.cpp
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_control_allocator_pub ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_control_allocator_pub
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(omnicopter_control_allocator_sub
  src/omnicopter_control_allocator_sub.cpp
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_control_allocator_sub ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_control_allocator_sub
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_library(omnicopter_position_controller
  include/omnicopter_controller/omnicopter_position_controller.h
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_position_controller ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_position_controller
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_library(omnicopter_attitude_controller
  include/omnicopter_controller/omnicopter_attitude_controller.h
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_attitude_controller ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_attitude_controller
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_library(omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller
  include/omnicopter_controller/omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller.h
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_library(omnicopter_control_allocator
  include/omnicopter_controller/omnicopter_control_allocator.h
)
add_dependencies(omnicopter_control_allocator ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(omnicopter_control_allocator
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>omnicopter_controller</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The omnicopter_controller package</description>

  <maintainer email="hdl@todo.todo">hdl</maintainer>  

  <author>Dingliang Huang</author>

  <license>TODO</license> 
  
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend> 


  <depend>rospy</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>
  <depend>cmake_modules</depend>
  <depend>dynamic_reconfigure</depend>
  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <depend>mav_msgs</depend>
  <depend>nav_msgs</depend>
  <depend>roscpp</depend>
  <depend>sensor_msgs</depend>

</package>
```

Below I show the exact errors.

errors:

```
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: omnicopter_position_controller
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "omnicopter_position_controller".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: omnicopter_attitude_controller
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "omnicopter_attitude_controller".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: omnicopter_control_allocator
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "omnicopter_control_allocator".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "omnicopter_body_angular_velocity_controller".
```

I wish someone can help me to solve these errors. I would appreciate it.

Comment: why are you trying to make libraries with no source files?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have solved the problems. These errors caused by lacking of set_target_properties(XX PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C++) after every add_library()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problems. These errors caused by lacking of set_target_properties(XX PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C++) after every add_library().